# Replace a loop with strtok by using Standard Library

Tags: c++, stl

I have a problem that strtok solves (split substrings from a string) but I
realize that strtok is not safe. I want to use some more modern parts of the C++ standard library.

What should I use instead?

```
static int ParseLine(std::string line, 
                     std::string seps, 
                     int startIdx, 
                     std::vector<CNode>& collection)
{
    if (startIdx > collection.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the start index is out of range");
    }
    char buf[2000];
    strcpy_s(buf, line.c_str());
    auto idx = startIdx;
    for (auto objectType = strtok(buf, seps.c_str()); objectType != nullptr; idx++)
    {
        if (idx == collection.size())
        {
            collection.push_back(CNode(idx));
        }
        collection[idx].SetObjectType(objectType);
        objectType = strtok(nullptr, seps.c_str());
    }
    return (idx - 1);
}
```

Here a complete sample that compiles with 
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class CObject
{
    std::string _objectType;

public:
                CObject() : _objectType("n/a") {}
    void        SetObjectType(std::string objectType) { _objectType = objectType; }
    std::string GetObjectType() const { return _objectType; }

};

class CNode
{
    int     _id;
    CObject _object;

public:
    explicit CNode(int id) : _id(id) {}
    void        SetObjectType(std::string objectType) { _object.SetObjectType(objectType); }
    std::string GetObjectType() const { return _object.GetObjectType(); }

};

// Update the collection of nodes with the object types found in the line specified.
// Return the number of elements in the collection.
static int ParseLine(std::string line, std::string seps, int startIdx, std::vector<CNode>& collection)
{
    if (startIdx > collection.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the start index is out of range");
    }
    char buf[2000];
    strcpy_s(buf, line.c_str());
    auto idx = startIdx;
    for (auto objectType = strtok(buf, seps.c_str()); objectType != nullptr; idx++)
    {
        if (idx == collection.size())
        {
            collection.push_back(CNode(idx));
        }
        collection[idx].SetObjectType(objectType);
        objectType = strtok(nullptr, seps.c_str());
    }
    return (idx - 1);
}

int main()
{
    std::string seps = ".";
    //                   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    std::string line = "abc.def.ghi.klm.nop.qrs.tuv.wxyz";
    std::vector<CNode> collection { CNode(0), CNode(1), CNode(2) , CNode(3) , CNode(4) , CNode(5) };
    auto startAt = 2;
    try
    {
        auto collection_size = ParseLine(line, seps, startAt, collection);
        std::cout << collection_size << std::endl;
        for (auto value : collection)
        {
            std::cout << value.GetObjectType() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument& e)
    {
        std::cout << " out of range exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How comfortable are you with Regular Expressions?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I never used regular expression but I'll dig for a solution in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples of splitting a delimited string.

The first uses `std::getline` with a string stream, specifying a separator character instead of using the default newline character.  Only single-character separators may be used with this technique.

The second example uses the `<regex>` library, which allows separators of arbitrary length and also gives you more control over how a separator is recognized.  Note that the dot character must be escaped in the regex specification, because in the regex language, "." acts as a wildcard.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

std::vector<std::string> GetlineSplit(std::string const& line) {
    static const char sep = '.';
    std::istringstream liness{line};
    std::vector<std::string> fields;
    for(std::string field; std::getline(liness, field, sep); ) {
        fields.push_back(field);
    }
    return fields;
}

std::vector<std::string> RegexSplit(std::string const& line) {
    std::regex seps("\\."); // the dot character needs to be escaped in a regex
    std::sregex_token_iterator rit(line.begin(), line.end(), seps, -1);
    return std::vector<std::string>(rit, std::sregex_token_iterator());
}

int main() {
    std::string line = "abc.def.ghi.klm.nop.qrs.tuv.wxyz";

    std::cout << "getline split result:\n";
    auto fields_getline = GetlineSplit(line);
    for(const auto& field : fields_getline) {
        std::cout << field << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "\nregex split result:\n";
    auto fields_regex = RegexSplit(line);
    for(const auto& field : fields_regex) {
        std::cout << field << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution using regex is concise and demonstrates a clear and practical case of how to replace strtok with the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Utility class that has nothing but static methods as you can not create an instance of this Utility class. I use this for various methods of working with strings from converting, to removing white space, splitting, changing cases etc. Here is a function to split a string from this class:

**Utility.h**

```
class Utility {
public:
    static std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, 
                                                 const std::string& strDelimiter, 
                                                 const bool keepEmpty = true );

private:
    Utility();
};
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
#include "Utility.h"

// splitString()
std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, 
                                               const std::string& strDelimiter, 
                                               const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }

    return vResult;

} // splitString
```

The needed library includes for this utility method to work are `<vector>`, `<string>` and `<algorithm>` which are mostly commonly used in almost all applications.

To use this function we can do a simple test as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include "Utility.h"

int main() {
    std::string someLongString2( "Hello World How Are You" );

    std::vector<std::string> singleWords;
    singleWords = Utility::splitString( someLongString, " " );

     // Space is the delimiter and now each individual word 
     // from the long string are now each a new string stored 
     // in this vector. You can use any character for your delimiter.
     // Also this function is not limited to having a single character
     // as its delimiter. You can use a series of characters or specific
     // words as your delimiter. Such as a comma followed by a space.

      std::string someLongString2( "Hello, World, How, Are, You" );
      singleWords.clear();
      singleWords = Utility::splitString( someLongString2, ", " );

    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: I like your Utility::splitString() method. Thanks very much.

Comment: @LessWhite well thank you very much; I technically didn't write it; but it was shown to me by another years ago when I was using VS2010 or 12 and its been in my collection ever since and I use this static class all the time: hence reusable :). I have about 10 - 20 methods in this utility class that come in handy without having to write them over and over again. Some were written by myself while some were written by others. If I was able to remember who showed me this function; I'd give them the credit for this but I still like to help others in their times of need.

Answer (score 0):

Below the solution to replace strtok using the standard library (using the answer received):

```
std::vector<std::string> SplitLine(std::string const& line, std::string seps)
{
    std::regex regxSeps(seps); // the dot character needs to be escaped in a regex
    std::sregex_token_iterator rit(line.begin(), line.end(), regxSeps, -1);
    return std::vector<std::string>(rit, std::sregex_token_iterator());
}

static int ParseLine(std::string line, std::string seps, size_t startIdx, std::vector<CNode>& collection)
{
    if (startIdx > collection.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the start index is out of range");
    }

    auto objectTypes = SplitLine(line, seps);

    auto idx = startIdx;
    for (const auto& objectType : objectTypes)
    {
        if (idx == collection.size())
        {
            collection.push_back(CNode(idx));
        }
        collection[idx++].SetObjectType(objectType);
    }
    return (idx - 1);
}

int main()
{
    std::string seps = "\\."; // the dot character needs to be escaped in a regex
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is anyone knows a way to replace the loop by calls to standard library? I've heard that most of the time, we should replace loops by calls to std.