# Replace the loops to insert and update a collection by the Standard Library

Tags: c++, stl

I have two loops to iterate a collection:

- the first one adds missing elements into the collection.
- the second one updates existing instances into the collection.

How can I replace the loops by standard library functions?

```
// add missing elements into the collection (if any)
for (auto i = collection.size(); i < objectTypes.size() + startIdx; i++)
{
    collection.push_back(CNode(i));
}

// update elements of the collection
for (const auto& objectType : objectTypes)
{
    collection[startIdx++].SetObjectType(objectType);
}
```

This question is a further step to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927642/replace-a-loop-with-strtok-by-using-standard-library).

Here a complete sample that compiles:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

class CObject
{
    std::string _objectType;

public:
    CObject() : _objectType("n/a") {}    
    void SetObjectType(std::string objectType) { _objectType = objectType; }
    std::string GetObjectType() const { return _objectType; }
};

class CNode
{
    int _id;
    CObject _object;

public:
    explicit CNode(int id) : _id(id) {}   
    void SetObjectType(std::string objectType) { _object.SetObjectType(objectType); }
    std::string GetObjectType() const { return _object.GetObjectType(); }
};

std::vector<std::string> SplitLine(std::string const& line, std::string seps)
{
    std::regex regxSeps(seps); // the dot character needs to be escaped in a regex
    std::sregex_token_iterator rit(line.begin(), line.end(), regxSeps, -1);
    return std::vector<std::string>(rit, std::sregex_token_iterator());
}

static int ParseLine(std::string line, std::string seps, size_t startIdx, std::vector<CNode>& collection)
{
    if (startIdx > collection.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the start index is out of range");
    }

    auto objectTypes = SplitLine(line, seps);

    for (auto missingIdx = collection.size(); missingIdx < objectTypes.size() + startIdx; missingIdx++)
    {
        collection.push_back(CNode(missingIdx));
    }

    for (const auto& objectType : objectTypes)
    {
        collection[startIdx++].SetObjectType(objectType);
    }

    return (startIdx - 1);
}

int main()
{
    std::string seps = "\\."; // the dot character needs to be escaped in a regex

    //                   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    std::string line = "abc.def.ghi.klm.nop.qrs.tuv.wxyz";
    std::vector<CNode> collection{ CNode(0), CNode(1), CNode(2) , CNode(3) , CNode(4) , CNode(5) };
    auto startAt = 2;
    try
    {
        auto collection_size = ParseLine(line, seps, startAt, collection);
        std::cout << collection_size << std::endl;
        for (auto value : collection)
        {
            std::cout << value.GetObjectType() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument& e)
    {
        std::cout << " out of range exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something similar to this would work (I have not tested it):

```
auto i = collection.size();

std::transform (objectTypes.begin(), objectTypes.end(),
    std::back_inserter(collection),
    [&](const ObjectType& ot) {
      CNode ct(++i);
      ct.SetObjectType(ot);
      return ct;
    });
```

Is there any reason also not to add an objectType parameter to the CNode constructor?

Comment: I have no problem adding an objectType parameter to the CNode ctor, but I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested to get the complete code of the function, below the final solution using the standard library to replace the two loops to insert and update the collection:

```
// Compute the number of elements to insert and to update
auto numInserts = startIdx + objectTypes.size() - collection.size();
auto numUpdates = collection.size() - startIdx;


// update the elements that already exists in the collection
std::for_each(  objectTypes.begin(),
                objectTypes.begin() + numUpdates,
                [&](const std::string objectType) 
                { collection[startIdx++].SetObjectType(objectType); });


// add the missing elements into the collection (if any)
std::transform( objectTypes.end() - numInserts,
                objectTypes.end(),
                std::back_inserter(collection),
                [&](const std::string& objectType) 
                { return CNode(++startIdx, objectType); });
```

Here a complete sample that compiles:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

class CObject
{
    std::string _objectType;

public:
    CObject() : _objectType("n/a") {}
    explicit CObject(std::string objectType) : _objectType(objectType) {};
    void SetObjectType(std::string objectType) { _objectType = objectType; }
    std::string GetObjectType() const { return _objectType; }
};

class CNode
{
    int _id;
    CObject _object;

public:
    explicit CNode(int id) : _id(id) {}
    explicit CNode(int id, std::string objectType) : _id(id), _object(objectType) {}
    void SetObjectType(std::string objectType) { _object.SetObjectType(objectType); }
    std::string GetObjectType() const { return _object.GetObjectType(); }
};

std::vector<std::string> SplitLine(std::string const& line, std::string seps)
{
    std::regex regxSeps(seps); // the dot character needs to be escaped in a regex
    std::sregex_token_iterator rit(line.begin(), line.end(), regxSeps, -1);
    return std::vector<std::string>(rit, std::sregex_token_iterator());
}

static int ParseLineWithLoops(std::string line, std::string seps, size_t startIdx, std::vector<CNode>& collection)
{
    if (startIdx > collection.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the start index is out of range");
    }

    auto objectTypes = SplitLine(line, seps);

    // expand the collection if needed 
    for (auto idx = collection.size(); idx < objectTypes.size() + startIdx; idx++)
    {
        collection.push_back(CNode(idx));
    }

    // update the types of elements into the collection
    for (const auto& objectType : objectTypes)
    {
        collection[startIdx++].SetObjectType(objectType);
    }

    return (startIdx - 1);
}

static int ParseLineWithStdTransform(std::string line, std::string seps, size_t startIdx, std::vector<CNode>& collection)
{
    if (startIdx > collection.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the start index is out of range");
    }

    auto objectTypes = SplitLine(line, seps);

    // Compute the number of elements to insert and to update
    auto numInserts = startIdx + objectTypes.size() - collection.size();
    auto numUpdates = collection.size() - startIdx;

    // update the elements that already exists in the collection
    std::for_each(  objectTypes.begin(),
                    objectTypes.begin() + numUpdates,
                    [&](const std::string objectType) { collection[startIdx++].SetObjectType(objectType); });


    // add the missing elements into the collection (if any)
    std::transform( objectTypes.end() - numInserts,
                    objectTypes.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(collection),
                    [&](const std::string& objectType) { return CNode(++startIdx, objectType); });

    return (collection.size() - 1);
}

int main()
{
    std::string seps = "\\."; // the dot character needs to be escaped in a regex

                              //                   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    std::string line = "abc.def.ghi.klm.nop.qrs.tuv.wxyz";
    auto startAt = 2;


    std::vector<CNode> collection1{ CNode(0), CNode(1), CNode(2) , CNode(3) , CNode(4) , CNode(5) };
    try
    {
        auto collection_size = ParseLineWithStdTransform(line, seps, startAt, collection1);
        std::cout << collection_size << std::endl;
        for (auto value : collection1)
        {
            std::cout << value.GetObjectType() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument& e)
    {
        std::cout << " out of range exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }



    std::vector<CNode> collection2{ CNode(0), CNode(1), CNode(2) , CNode(3) , CNode(4) , CNode(5) };
    try
    {
        auto collection_size = ParseLineWithLoops(line, seps, startAt, collection2);
        std::cout << collection_size << std::endl;
        for (auto value : collection2)
        {
            std::cout << value.GetObjectType() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument& e)
    {
        std::cout << " out of range exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```